# I'm trying to set up a home connection from Ubuntu to Win 10

Tags: networking, windows-10

I am trying to file share from Ubuntu 20.04 desktop to Win 10 laptop.  I live in Welsh hills with no neighbours and no landline (too slow) but have good data via iPhone or iPad (usually 25 to 30 Mb).  I have installed Samba and shared necessary directory's and ticking guest.  From Ubuntu I get "folder empty" when I click on Windows Network with nothing found from Win laptop network.
I have had this working a long time ago with Win 7 (although that was with BT landline/hub) but cannot connect since Win 10.  All the  "how to's" I've found refer to things no longer available in Win 10.  I can use terminal and command prompt but don't have the knowledge to know what to type.  Or is it impossible to file share with my setup?

Comment: Do the machines involved have ip address?

Comment: How do I find that out please?

Comment: A quick google search brings up the info. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-findip.html.en

Comment: For Ubuntu
IPv4 172.20.10.3
IPv6 fe80::8946:6694:eaeb:5618
DNS  172.20.10.1

Comment: You have shared the folder on the windows side?

Comment: Certainly I have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119199/discussion-between-vic-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

If your computers are online, you can set up a filezilla/ftp server on the windows 10 computer and download filezilla client on the ubuntu computer. Then, you can use private ip adderesses (ipconfig on windows and ifconfig in ubuntu) to connect to your laptop in the filezilla client. I used it for my school, and it just works (for me).

Comment: Thank you I will try that when I get another problem solved (Ubuntu keeps dropping WiFi)

Comment: Depending on the situation, you can also use ethernet

Comment: I don't have Ethernet as stated in question.

Comment: thats ok, but I can't see it in the quistion right now...

Comment: "no landline" in first sentence.

Comment: aah, ok. I understand